# GridBagLayout panel expands ignoring BoxLayout's vertical glue

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

In the example below I have a JPanel with BoxLayout which contains another JPanel with GridBagLayout.

By adding a vertical glue I expect the contents of the inner panel to be "glued" to the top of the outer panel.

But I see the label "A" in the center.  If I remove GridBagLayout, A is shown at the top. 
Why does this happen?

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();        

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel gridBagPanel = new JPanel();
        gridBagPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        gridBagPanel.add(new JLabel("A"), gbc);
        contentPane.add(gridBagPanel);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default value of the `anchor` property of `GridBagConstraints` is `CENTER`. If there is more space in the inner panel than the preferred size of the JLabel, the JLabel would be centered with respect to the available space in the inner panel (since you set fill to NONE).

You can use the anchor value `NORTHWEST` to glue the label to the top of the panel:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.weightx = 1;
```

You also need to set the weights per Java documentation: "Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container. *This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the default), the GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.*"

Comment: Thanks but does not help with my example, A still in the center with above code added.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `GridBagLayout` is a pain in the butt and you should consider using other layout managers.  Or it could be that you need to set the horizontal and vertical alignment of your components.  Take a look at `setAlignmentX` and `setAlignmentY` of [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).  Whenever I've had misbehaved components it's because I didn't align everything the same.

Comment: Thanks, but adding
    JLabel l = new JLabel("A");
    l.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    ...
did not help

Answer (score 0):

Although [Kavka s' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671732/gridbaglayout-panel-expands-ignoring-boxlayouts-vertical-glue/8671950#8671950) solves the requirement of having A on the top of the panel by using an anchor, I believe the declared vertical glue in the BoxLayout Panel doesn't actually do anything. So, I am going to expand on this to contribute what I figured out about using the weights and the vertical glue in GridBagLayouts.

Since GridBagLayout is a complex one, there may be more than one reason, but as Kavka already pointed out:

> the **`weightx`** and **`weighty`** modification from default value 0.0 to a **non-zero** value is the key.

As pointed out in the [Java Tutorial Documentation on GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagConstraints) , in the description section of the [JavaDoc for GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) and the specific parameter description in the [JavaDoc for GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx).

> If all the weights are zero, all the extra space appears between the grids of the cell and
>
> - for **weightx** the extra space appears additionally between the left and right edges.
> - for **weighty** the extra space appears additionally between the top and bottom edges.

So, if you wanted to use some vertical glue to fill empty cells you need to make sure you give a **non-zero** weight to the glue component in the direction you would like it to expand. I am going to solely use the GridBagLayout, so the `gridy` parameter is going to allow me to define the vertical distribution of the components.

Taking the original code as example base and extending it a bit to demonstrate the capabilities of vertical glue in combination with weights. This code will position A at 20% from the top of the panel, maintaining this ratio when resized:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel gridBagPanel = new JPanel();
        gridBagPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.2;
        gridBagPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gridBagPanel.add(new JLabel("A"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 0.8;
        gridBagPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), gbc);

        frame.setContentPane(gridBagPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

For specifics on how the glue works see [Java Tutorial on How to Use BoxLayout, Filler section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler)